# How to fix api.nvim?

Tags: neovim

Probably a noob question, this is my first week with neovim and can't use any "api.nvim" functions.
I'm on windows 10 and downloaded nvim-win64.zip from here:
https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/

```
vim.api.nvim.set_keymap("key1", "key2")
```

> Error detected while processing :source (no file):
> E5108: Error executing lua [string ":source (no file)"]:3: attempt to > index field 'nvim' (a nil value)
> stack traceback:
> [string ":source (no file)"]:3: in main chunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using correctly Neovim API, see [docs for Neovim API](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html) for details.

To use [`nvim_set_keymap`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_set_keymap()), the correct syntax is: `vim.api.nvim_set_keymap`